# Two toolbar in header QtQuickCOntrols 2

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols, qtquickcontrols2

I start on Qt Quick and I want to develop an application that will be deployed on an embedded system. I'm using Qt Quick Controls 2. I'm trying to create two toolbars in my header: a toolbar consisting of icons (battery level, network connection, ...) and a toolbar allowing to navigate in a StackView (as in the example Gallery provided by Qt). I would like to have two different background colors for each toolbar[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE3in.png). For now I have a header that have a toolbar and do the levels get organized with a ColumnLayout and two RowLayout.
How could I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Material.primary](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-material.html#material-primary-attached-prop) attached property to specify the Material style ToolBar color. For example:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    header: Column {
        ToolBar {
            Material.primary: Material.Red
        }
        ToolBar {
            Material.primary: Material.Blue
        }
    }
}
```